# ResourceException when creating IMarker on IFile (linked resource)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have some problems updating an "old" Eclipse plugin. Here is what I would like to do and what the original plugin did:

(parse compiler output on console with file name and error information --> still works)

--> set link to the location within the file
--> set marker to location in the file

What I did in the past was to get the IFile from the path String of the file and generated link and marker from it:

```
IFile ifile;
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IPath path = new Path(fileName);

IFiles[] files = workspace.getRoot().findFilesForLocation(path);
...
ifile = iFiles[0];

Map attributes = new HashMap();

attributes.put(IMarker.SEVERITY, new Integer (severity));

MarkerUtilities.setLineNumber(attributes, lineNumber);
MarkerUtilities.setMessage(attributes, message);
MarkerUtilities.createMarker(ifile, attributes,
        IMarker
```

Since findFilesForLocation is deprecated, I tried to find another way but I am not succeeding whatsoever. Using the changed code to get the IFile always results in a exception: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/path/to/file.c' does not exist.
Is it possible that this relates to the fact that the source file is only linked into the project, and not physically within the project?

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IPath location = new Path(fileName);
IFile ifile = workspace.getRoot().getFile(location);
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `fileName` is the fully qualified path to the file you want to get.  I'm also guessing that the file that you are looking for is already in the workspace, even if it is linked (if not, then this won't work.  You will first need to add the file to a project before getting the IFile for it).

You need to do something like this:

```
IFiles[] files = workspace.getRoot().findFilesForLocationURI("file:" + fileName);
```

Then this will find all files in the workspace that correspond to the file in the file system.

The reason why your attempt above is giving you a `ResourceException` is that you are trying to pass in a file system path to get an IFile object from the workspace.  The Eclipse workspace is an abstraction over the underlying filesystem and cannot directly work with absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

For the Resources APIs, Paths usually means a path in the workspace and Location usually refers to a place in the filesystem or outside the workspace.  If you already have a workspace path to start with, just ask the IWorkspaceRoot for the IFile and get on with what you're doing.